# 'OperationLog' is not supported when running ETM rules

Tags: permissions, territory-management

According to the [ETM deployment guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_implementing_territory_mgmt2_guide.pdf), in order to run assignment rules a user needs the *Customize Application* and *Manage Territories* permissions.  This is not correct.

The result is an error that the object OperationLog is not supports and is this some kind of custom object.  I found the solution which I'll post next.  Just want to put this out in the world since it took a little digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OperationLog object mentioned in the error is part of the Tooling API which is apparently used under the hood of this process.  *View All Data* is required to use the Tooling API.  So that must also be added in addition to the other two.  See [this thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DC4yIAG).

I confirmed this works in a sandbox.  This is either a bug in Salesforce v38 (setting up the batch operation should be done under automatically elevated privileges) or a bug in the docs.